# SSL doesn't deliver parts of Wordpress Administration Module

Tags: wp-admin, htaccess, ssl

I have a very strange problem in my website. Let me figure it out:

Firstly I have an SSL website https://example.com when I log in into /wp-admin i can't see some features like my Media Library or my stats on Jetpack. Everything solved when i access the Administration Wordpress mod without SSL.

The first screenshot shows the SSL condition and the second the nonSSL.

[image: SSL]
[image: nonSSL]

Furthermore, i was trying to change the WordPress and Site Address from General Settings but it was unsuccessful.

Finally, my .htaccess file is :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I would like to have every link in my website under SSL protocol.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You've changed the addresses from general settings, is it also in your `wp-config.php` file? And is it registering the new https:// in general settings?

Comment: I changed my address through general settings from https to http and remove the rules from .htaccess file for HTTPS redirecting, so i could resolve the problem.

Also when I'm trying to access example.com/wp-admin I'm redirecting to :

https://example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

Comment: what kind of SSL certificate do you have? You might have something on that page which isn't ssl certified so there's a minor chance it's effecting the page - your cert on the address bar can enlighten you to any issues like that.

Comment: @Aravona thanks for the reply. My SSL cert is Domain certified Rapid SSL.